# I Need to Edit Part of this Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

I want to edit the fifth element which is the last and the element at the bottom right of this picture. I want to change it to be (the first to the fourth element) I do not know how to go about it.

[image: Here is the output of what I tried]

See what I have tried

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{plane/.style n args={3}{insert path={%
            #1 -- ++ #2 -- ++ #3 -- ++ ($-1*#2$) -- cycle}},
    unit xy plane/.style={plane={#1}{(1,0,0)}{(0,1,0)}},
    unit xz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(1,0,0)}{(0,0,1)}},
    unit yz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(0,1,0)}{(0,0,1)}},
    get projections/.style={insert path={%
            let \p1=(1,0,0),\p2=(0,1,0)  in 
            [/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xproj}{sign(\x1)}\xdef\xproj{\xproj}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yproj}{sign(\x2)}\xdef\yproj{\yproj}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zproj} 
   {sign(cos(\tdplotmaintheta))}\xdef\zproj{\zproj}}]}},
    pics/unit cube/.style={code={
            \path[get projections];
            \draw (0,0,0) -- (1,1,1);
            \ifnum\zproj=-1
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xy face,unit xy plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
            \fi
            \ifnum\yproj=1
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/yz face,unit yz plane={(1,0,0)}]; 
            \else
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/yz face,unit yz plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
            \fi
            \ifnum\xproj=1
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xz face,unit xz plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
            \else
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xz face,unit xz plane={(0,1,0)}]; 
            \fi
            \ifnum\zproj>-1
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xy face,unit xy plane={(0,0,1)}]; 
            \fi
    }},
    3d cube/.cd,
    xy face/.style={fill=blue!10},
    xz face/.style={fill=blue!20},
    yz face/.style={fill=blue!30},
    num cubes x/.estore in=\NumCubesX,
    num cubes y/.estore in=\NumCubesY,
    num cubes z/.estore in=\NumCubesZ,
    num cubes x=1,num cubes y/.initial=1,num cubes z/.initial=1,
    cube scale/.initial=0.9,
    every face/.style={draw,very thick},
    /tikz/pics/.cd,
    cube array/.style={code={%
            \tikzset{3d cube/.cd,#1}
            %\typeout{\NumCubesX,\NumCubesY,\NumCubesZ}
            \path[get projections];
            \ifnum\yproj=1
            \def\LstX{1,...,\NumCubesX}
            \else 
            \ifnum\NumCubesX>1
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextToLast}{\NumCubesX-1}
            \def\LstX{\NumCubesX,\NextToLast,...,1}
            \else
            \def\LstX{1}   
            \fi 
            \fi
            \ifnum\xproj=-1
            \def\LstY{1,...,\NumCubesY}
            \else 
            \ifnum\NumCubesY>1
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextToLast}{\NumCubesX-1}
            \def\LstY{\NumCubesY,\NextToLast,...,1}
            \else
            \def\LstY{1}   
            \fi 
            \fi
            \ifnum\zproj=1
            \def\LstZ{1,...,\NumCubesZ}
            \else 
            \ifnum\NumCubesZ>1
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextToLast}{\NumCubesX-1}
            \def\LstZ{\NumCubesZ,\NextToLast,...,1}
            \else
            \def\LstZ{1}   
            \fi 
            \def\LstZ{\NumCubesZ,\NextToLast,...,1}
            \fi
            \foreach \X in \LstX
            {\foreach \Y in \LstY
            {\foreach \Z in \LstZ
                    {\path (\X-\NumCubesX/2-1,\Y-\NumCubesY/2-1,\Z-\NumCubesY/2-1)
                        pic[scale=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d cube/cube scale}]{unit cube};}}
            } 
    }}
}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{200} % the first argument cannot be larger than 90
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,font=\sffamily,3d cube/.cd,
    num cubes x=1,num cubes y=1,num cubes z=1]
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=first row]
            \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,local bounding box=scalar]
                \path pic{cube array={num cubes x=1}};
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,tdplot_main_coords,local bounding box=vector]
                \path pic{cube array={num cubes x=3}};
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,tdplot_main_coords,local bounding box=matrix]
                \path pic{cube array={num cubes x=3,num cubes z=3}};
            \end{scope}
            %\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,tdplot_main_coords,local bounding box=array]
                %\path pic{cube array={num cubes x=3,num cubes y=3,num cubes z=3}};
            %\end{scope}
        \end{scope}
        \foreach \X in {scalar, vector, matrix}
        {\node[above] at (\X|-first row.north){\X};}
        %
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-5.5cm,local bounding box=data frame,tdplot_main_coords]
            \foreach \Col [count=\XX] in {blue,purple,green}
            {\path (2-\XX,0,0)pic{cube array={num cubes z=3,
                        xy face/.style={fill=\Col!5},
                        xz face/.style={fill=\Col!10},
                        yz face/.style={fill=\Col!15}}};}
        \end{scope}
        \node[above] (df) at (data frame.north){data frame};
        %
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-3.5cm,xshift=5cm,local bounding box=list]
            \path foreach \xy in {-1.5,0,1.5}
            {(\xy,0,0) pic[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.4]{cube array={num cubes x=1,num cubes y=3,num cubes z=3,cube scale=0.36}}};
        \end{scope}
        \node at (df-|list){list};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**What I Want**

I want the three small element at the down-rigth cornal to be four(`scalar`, `vector`, `matrix` and `data frame`).

This is the part I want to change

```
        %
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-3.5cm,xshift=5cm,local bounding box=list]
            \path foreach \xy in {-1.5,0,1.5}
            {(\xy,0,0) pic[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.4]{cube array={num cubes x=1,num cubes y=3,num cubes z=3,cube scale=0.36}}};
        \end{scope}
        \node at (df-|list){list};
```

The foreach function is making it difficult for me to handle.

Comment: Out of interest: Was this code automatically generated by software or manually by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a complex picture --- I wouldn't really call it a minimal example. But without knowing anything about the 3d parts, **and** if I understood correctly what you wanted, I tried to mimic what is done in the rest of the and then played by trial and error with the coordinates. If you change the last part with

```latex
\begin{scope}[yshift=-5.5cm,xshift=5cm,local bounding box=list]
            % use a parametric \nx, \ny, \nz for the first three object
            \path foreach \xy/\nx/\ny/\nz in 
                {-1.5/1/1/1,0/3/1/1,1.5/3/1/3}
            {(\xy,0,0) pic[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.4]{cube array={num cubes x=\nx,num cubes y=\ny,num cubes z=\nz,cube scale=0.36}}};
            % the last one is a different object, for the colors, so do that
            % alone
            \foreach \Col [count=\XX] in {blue,purple,green}
                {\path (4.2-0.43*\XX,-0.4+0.1*\XX,0)pic[tdplot_main_coords, scale=0.4] {cube array={num cubes z=3,
                        xy face/.style={fill=\Col!5},
                        xz face/.style={fill=\Col!10},
                        yz face/.style={fill=\Col!15},
                        cube scale=0.36}};}
\end{scope}
```

You will obtain:

[image: output from the snippet below]

The code utilizes one of the most useful feature of `\foreach`: stepping over several values. If you write

```
\foreach \x/\y in {1/A, 2/B, 3/C} { ... };
```

the code in `{...}` will be "run" three times and `\x` and `\y` will take the value specified: in the first loop, `\x` will be `1` and `\y` will be `A`; in the second one, `\x` → `2` and `\y` → `B`; and so on. You can have any number of  parts separated by `/`; in the case of the answer I used 4 of them (the position, the number of x cubes, the number of y cubes, and the number of z cubes).

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{plane/.style n args={3}{insert path={%
            #1 -- ++ #2 -- ++ #3 -- ++ ($-1*#2$) -- cycle}},
    unit xy plane/.style={plane={#1}{(1,0,0)}{(0,1,0)}},
    unit xz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(1,0,0)}{(0,0,1)}},
    unit yz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(0,1,0)}{(0,0,1)}},
    get projections/.style={insert path={%
            let \p1=(1,0,0),\p2=(0,1,0)  in 
            [/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xproj}{sign(\x1)}\xdef\xproj{\xproj}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yproj}{sign(\x2)}\xdef\yproj{\yproj}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zproj} 
   {sign(cos(\tdplotmaintheta))}\xdef\zproj{\zproj}}]}},
    pics/unit cube/.style={code={
            \path[get projections];
            \draw (0,0,0) -- (1,1,1);
            \ifnum\zproj=-1
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xy face,unit xy plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
            \fi
            \ifnum\yproj=1
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/yz face,unit yz plane={(1,0,0)}]; 
            \else
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/yz face,unit yz plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
            \fi
            \ifnum\xproj=1
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xz face,unit xz plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
            \else
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xz face,unit xz plane={(0,1,0)}]; 
            \fi
            \ifnum\zproj>-1
            \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xy face,unit xy plane={(0,0,1)}]; 
            \fi
    }},
    3d cube/.cd,
    xy face/.style={fill=blue!10},
    xz face/.style={fill=blue!20},
    yz face/.style={fill=blue!30},
    num cubes x/.estore in=\NumCubesX,
    num cubes y/.estore in=\NumCubesY,
    num cubes z/.estore in=\NumCubesZ,
    num cubes x=1,num cubes y/.initial=1,num cubes z/.initial=1,
    cube scale/.initial=0.9,
    every face/.style={draw,very thick},
    /tikz/pics/.cd,
    cube array/.style={code={%
            \tikzset{3d cube/.cd,#1}
            %\typeout{\NumCubesX,\NumCubesY,\NumCubesZ}
            \path[get projections];
            \ifnum\yproj=1
            \def\LstX{1,...,\NumCubesX}
            \else 
            \ifnum\NumCubesX>1
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextToLast}{\NumCubesX-1}
            \def\LstX{\NumCubesX,\NextToLast,...,1}
            \else
            \def\LstX{1}   
            \fi 
            \fi
            \ifnum\xproj=-1
            \def\LstY{1,...,\NumCubesY}
            \else 
            \ifnum\NumCubesY>1
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextToLast}{\NumCubesX-1}
            \def\LstY{\NumCubesY,\NextToLast,...,1}
            \else
            \def\LstY{1}   
            \fi 
            \fi
            \ifnum\zproj=1
            \def\LstZ{1,...,\NumCubesZ}
            \else 
            \ifnum\NumCubesZ>1
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextToLast}{\NumCubesX-1}
            \def\LstZ{\NumCubesZ,\NextToLast,...,1}
            \else
            \def\LstZ{1}   
            \fi 
            \def\LstZ{\NumCubesZ,\NextToLast,...,1}
            \fi
            \foreach \X in \LstX
            {\foreach \Y in \LstY
            {\foreach \Z in \LstZ
                    {\path (\X-\NumCubesX/2-1,\Y-\NumCubesY/2-1,\Z-\NumCubesY/2-1)
                        pic[scale=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/3d cube/cube scale}]{unit cube};}}
            } 
    }}
}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{200} % the first argument cannot be larger than 90
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,font=\sffamily,3d cube/.cd,
    num cubes x=1,num cubes y=1,num cubes z=1]
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=first row]
            \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,local bounding box=scalar]
                \path pic{cube array={num cubes x=1}};
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,tdplot_main_coords,local bounding box=vector]
                \path pic{cube array={num cubes x=3}};
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,tdplot_main_coords,local bounding box=matrix]
                \path pic{cube array={num cubes x=3,num cubes z=3}};
            \end{scope}
            %\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,tdplot_main_coords,local bounding box=array]
                %\path pic{cube array={num cubes x=3,num cubes y=3,num cubes z=3}};
            %\end{scope}
        \end{scope}
        \foreach \X in {scalar, vector, matrix}
        {\node[above] at (\X|-first row.north){\X};}
        %
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-5.5cm,local bounding box=data frame,tdplot_main_coords]
            \foreach \Col [count=\XX] in {blue,purple,green}
            {\path (2-\XX,0,0)pic{cube array={num cubes z=3,
                        xy face/.style={fill=\Col!5},
                        xz face/.style={fill=\Col!10},
                        yz face/.style={fill=\Col!15}}};}
        \end{scope}
        \node[above] (df) at (data frame.north){data frame};
        %
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-5.5cm,xshift=5cm,local bounding box=list]
            % use a parametric \nx, \ny, \nz for the first three object
            \path foreach \xy/\nx/\ny/\nz in 
                {-1.5/1/1/1,0/3/1/1,1.5/3/1/3}
            {(\xy,0,0) pic[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.4]{cube array={num cubes x=\nx,num cubes y=\ny,num cubes z=\nz,cube scale=0.36}}};
            % the last one is a different object, for the colors, so do that
            % alone
            \foreach \Col [count=\XX] in {blue,purple,green}
                {\path (4.2-0.43*\XX,-0.4+0.1*\XX,0)pic[tdplot_main_coords, scale=0.4] {cube array={num cubes z=3,
                        xy face/.style={fill=\Col!5},
                        xz face/.style={fill=\Col!10},
                        yz face/.style={fill=\Col!15},
                        cube scale=0.36}};}
        \end{scope}
        \node at (df-|list){list};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this aspect for me `{-1.5/1/1/1,0/3/1/1,1.5/3/1/3}`?

Comment: @DanielJames done! I hope it helps,

Comment: I can relate with the first numbers after the comma(`-1.5, 0, 1.5`) as a seq(`-1.5, 3,1.5`) what about the last two numbers before commas {`/1/1, 3/1, 1,3`}?

Comment: No, there are 4 variables in the iteration: the position, the number of x cubes, the number of y cubes and the number of the z cubes. The only thing the foreach does is to assign the 4 numbers, on every step of the loop, to `\xy`, `\nx`, `\ny`, and `\nz` respectively.

Comment: I asked the above question in my comment because I may want to add to those four elements or remove from it.

Comment: Yep, I understand. You can look at it here: https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf.back/foreach

Answer (score 2):

The foreach is setting the position of each of the three shapes, to get a fourth one try adding another number to it like this:

```
\path foreach \xy in {-1.5,0,1.5,3.0}
```

Since they are each 1.5 apart I added 1.5 to the last value to get 3.0.

Also, to get the shapes lower so the text is not on top of them you can change this line:

```
{(\xy,0,0) pic[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.4]{cube array={num cubes x=1,num cubes y=3,num cubes z=3,cube scale=0.36}}};
```

to:

```
{(\xy,-1.0,0) pic[tdplot_main_coords,scale=0.4]{cube array={num cubes x=1,num cubes y=3,num cubes z=3,cube scale=0.36}}};
```

This will move the images down the page a bit.

This will give you this result:
[image]

Comment: Ah, I missed that you wanted to change it from list to one each of the other four, I'll leave this as it may be helpful to someone anyway.

Comment: I will need your approach to the question as I want to enjoy different views.